# WPF TextBlock wrap inside TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview, word-wrap

How to make a TextBlock that is nested inside TreeView wrap when Window is resized? It's easy to do when TextBlock width is fixed i.e. 100, but I can't find a solution when width is resizable.

Below code is the closest I got to. TextBlocks are inside WrapPanel that is getting width from the parent TreeView. It doesn't work when treeviewitems are expanded, when indentation is actually "pushing" WrapPanel to the right, and hiding the rightmost text.

```
<TreeView 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
            ItemsSource="{Binding KeynoteModelHierarchy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
            <WrapPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeynoteCategoryNumber}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeynoteText}" 
                    TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Does it work TextWrapping="Wrap"?

Comment: Hi lidqy. No, it doesn't. The issue is that I'm setting the width of the TextBlock to the width of the TreeView. It works well on the top parent TreeViewItem, but when indentation comes in, the TextBlock width should be TreeView width - whitespace of indentiation and i don't know how to achieve that